# How do I deal with the Tension of this system?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces

I am currently working on a problem and I have trouble simulating the coupled dynamics of this system. There's a Quadrotor with a suspended payload.  I have developed the dynamics(translational and rotational) for the quadrotor and the payload and I used the constraint :
$$\|X_q-X_p\|=c$$
I differentiated the constraint two times in order to make the accelerations appear and then I substituted the dynamics to this equation. But how do I deal with the $T$ force (tension of cable)?
Is there some way to *"delete"* this force and the torque that produces?

Comment: is the T force the constraint force?

Comment: Yes , it is our constraint force

Answer (score 0):

Look at this Pendulum example:

\begin{align*}
&\textbf{the equations of motion}\\
&m\,\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
     \ddot{x} \\
     \ddot{y} \\
   \end{bmatrix}}_{\boldsymbol{\ddot{w}}}=\begin{bmatrix}
                   0 \\
                   -m\,g \\
                 \end{bmatrix}+\boldsymbol{C}^T_B\,\boldsymbol\lambda\tag 1\\
&\textbf{constraint equation}\\
&f_c=x^2+y^2-L^2=0\\
&\dot{f}_c= \underbrace{\frac{\partial f_c}{\partial \boldsymbol{w}}}_{\boldsymbol C_B}\,\boldsymbol{\dot{w}}  \\
&\ddot{f}_c= \boldsymbol C_B\, \boldsymbol{\ddot{w}}  +\frac{\partial (C_B\,\boldsymbol{\dot{w}})}{\partial \boldsymbol{w}} \,\boldsymbol{\dot{w}} \tag 2 \\
&\text{put Eq. (2) in (1) and sort you obtain}\\
&\boldsymbol A\,\begin{bmatrix}
                  \boldsymbol{\ddot{w}} \\
                  \boldsymbol\lambda \\
                \end{bmatrix}=\boldsymbol b\tag 3\\
&\boldsymbol A= \left[ \begin {array}{ccc} m&0&-2\,x\\ 0&m&-2\,y
\\-2\,x&-2\,y&0\end {array} \right]  \\
&\boldsymbol b= \left[ \begin {array}{c} 0\\ -m\,g
\\ -2\,{{\dot x}}^{2}-2\,{{\dot y}}^{2}\end {array}
 \right]              
\end{align*}
thus from  Eq. (3) you obtain $~\ddot{x}~,\ddot{y}~$ and the generalized force $~\lambda~$ notice that the initial conditions must fulfil the constraint equation $~x(0)^2+y(0)^2-L^2=0$